# Why does this perl script run way slower than it's c counterpart?

Tags: c, perl

I was solving [this](http://www.spoj.com/problems/ACPC10A/) trivial spoj problem in perl. So I came up with this solution:

```
while ("0 0 0\n" ne ($string = <STDIN>)) {
  my @a = split ' ', $string;
  $a1 = $a[0];
  $a2 = $a[1];
  $a3 = $a[2];

  if($a2 - $a1 == $a3 - $a2) {
    $c  = $a2 - $a1;
    $a4 = $a3 + $c;
    print("AP ", $a4);
  }
  else {
    $c  = $a2 / $a1;
    $a4 = $a3 * $c;
    print("GP ", $a4);
  }

  print "\n";
}
```

To my surprise, it exceeded the time limit. When I tried the same thing in C, it run successfully with a minimal run time.Here is the C version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a1, a2, a3, a4, c;
  while (1) {
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a1, &a2, &a3);
    if (a1 == 0 && a2 == 0 && a3 == 0) break;
    if (a2 - a1 == a3 - a2) {
      c  = a2 - a1;
      a4 = a3 + c;
      printf("AP %d\n", a4);
    }
    else {
      c  = a2 / a1;
      a4 = a3 * c;
      printf("GP %d\n", a4);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

So, could you please tell me:

Is perl really that much (200x at least) slower than C when it comes to this problem? I suspect it has to do with the input and the high level structures such as arrays used, or maybe there is a bug in my code causing the program to stall.

Comment: Indentation.  It's your friend.

Comment: *To my surprise, it exceeded the time limit.* What time limit? Also, C is a compiled language that compiles very efficiently, whereas Perl is an interpreted language. A two order-of-magnitude difference in performance could be expected. See http://attractivechaos.github.io/plb/, for example.

Comment: Your C and Perl code are not exactly the same.  Example: in perl you have some string comparisons before you split the string, where in C you split then compare as numbers.  You should make sure your code is exactly the same algorithm and redo your tests.  This may make no difference in the end, but it does't help anything to use different algorithms...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are various things wrong with your benchmark:

- The programs are not absolutely equivalent.
- At least your Perl code is unidiomatic (you didn't even declare all your variables!)

But most importantly:

- This benchmark is IO-based.
- If the input isn't large, startup time is also relevant.

The calculations you do are absolutely cheap, the most expensive part is reading and scanning for input. It is no suprise that the minimal C will be faster here than the higher-level PerlIO system.

Another thing you don't realize is that Perl is an *interpreted language*, whereas C is usually compiled. In the case of Perl, there is actually a C program that looks at certain data structures (opcodes) and depending on certain flags does addition, multiplication, branching, or comparision. Perl variables are scalars, which are actually an `SV*` - a pointer to an SV struct. These structs are considerably larger than an `int`. Each time a Perl program is executed, the `perl` interpreter parses and compiles the whole source code to the opcodes.

C, on the other hand, compiles to machine code which is more efficient than opcodes. This is done ahead of execution, so that compilation time is not factored into this benchmark. Startup will be faster for this reason. C can be optimized to use registers instead of locations on the heap, which makes simple data structures like `int`s much faster. The IO system in the C standard library is far more bare-bones than the complex system Perl has (decoding layers, buffering). All in all, C has fewer levels of indirections than Perl.

Because perl is a C program, these levels of indirections make Perl ~100× slower. The gap widens for math-heavy benchmarks (SV is more expensive than ints), but is closer for string operations like `index` and regexes.

For the record, here is a idiomatic version of your Perl code. No, it won't run faster.

```
while (<>) {
  last if $_ eq "0 0 0\n";
  my ($a1, $a2, $a3) = split;

  if($a2 - $a1 == $a3 - $a2) {
    my $a4 = $a3 + $a2 - $a1;
    print "AP $a4\n";
  }
  else {
    my $a4 = $a3 * $a2 / $a1;
    print "GP $a4\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping that something was wrong with my perl code:( Well, it seems that spoj test cases were just too many for perl to handle.Thanks for pointing out that my 2 programs are not equivalent, that was a stupid mistake.Oh, and the reason I didn't use too many idioms was because I knew it would make no difference as far as speed is concerned, since perl code goes through many layers of optimization.

Comment: @byrondrossos perl does optimize, but as compilation is part of the runtime it is careful not to do too much (compare how long compilation of a complex C program takes with `-O0` and `-O3`). The perl interpreter shares this 100×C performance region with other bytecode interpreters, e.g. for Ruby or Python. There are technologies to make these interpreters faster (Just-In-Time compilation that produces highly optimized machine code) but no mature JIT compiler for Perl exists.