# Why is this Perl loop over strings then characters so slow?

Tags: c, string, perl

The loop in the following Perl code snippet takes 210 seconds to run when $insertPoint is 101000 and $records is 3167. Equivalent C code  runs in a second or so on this machine (see below).  Usually when a factor of ~200X in run time appears it means something grossly inefficient is going on.

Any idea what it might be here?

@alignedSeqs is an array of strings, all the same length.  The machine has 80G of RAM and 8M of cache per CPU.  As far as I can tell this code goes "the right way" through memory.

```
   my $i;
   my $j;
   my @As=(0) x $insertPoint; # possibly faster than an array of arrays?
   my @Gs=(0) x $insertPoint;
   my @Cs=(0) x $insertPoint;
   my @Ts=(0) x $insertPoint;
   my @Is=(0) x $insertPoint;
   for($i=0;$i<$records;++$i){
      for($j=0; $j <$insertPoint; ++$j){
         my $base=uc(substr($alignedSeqs[$i],$j,1));
         if(   $base eq "A"){ $As[$j]++; }
         elsif($base eq "G"){ $Gs[$j]++; }
         elsif($base eq "C"){ $Cs[$j]++; }
         elsif($base eq "T"){ $Ts[$j]++; }
         else{                $Is[$j]++; }
      }
   }
```

This change:

```
  my $aSeq=$alignedSeqs[$i];
  for($j=0; $j <$insertPoint; ++$j){
     my $base=uc(substr($aSeq,$j,1));
```

made no significant difference in run time.

One clue to the nature of the problem may be the memory usage shown in "top" for this process while it runs, which peaks at over 12G before this code starts, and remains there throughout this section.  Then I changed the script to explicitly release the other large data structures in this program, and it dropped to 10G.  Assuming that most of this remaining 10G is in the aligned data that is not very efficient storage, since at one byte per character it should only take ~320M to hold these strings, or maybe 1.28G if Perl uses 4 byte unicode.

Here is a small C test program, just enough to exercise the equivalent code.  It is hard to time it precisely with my watch, but the "counting" part takes about 1-2 seconds when run like this:

gcc -std=c99 --pedantic -Wall -o test test.c
time ./test >/dev/null

and the whole thing completes in 7.1s.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h> //for toupper

// prototypes
void boom(char *string);

int main(void){

int records =   3167;
int slen    = 101000;
char **aligned=NULL;
malloc(sizeof(char *)*slen);
int i,j;
unsigned int k;


   aligned=malloc(sizeof(char *)*slen);
   if(!aligned)boom(" Could not allocate first array");

   fprintf(stderr,"DEBUG:  filling with random data\n");
   for(i=0;i<records;i++){
      aligned[i]=malloc(sizeof(char)*(slen+1));
      if(!aligned[i])boom(" Could not allocate an aligned array");
      for(j=0;j<slen;j++){
         k=rand();
         k -=((k>>10)<<10);
         switch(k){
            case 0:  aligned[i][j]='A'; break;
            case 1:  aligned[i][j]='C'; break;
            case 2:  aligned[i][j]='G'; break;
            case 3:  aligned[i][j]='T'; break;
            default: aligned[i][j]='-'; break;
         }
      } 
   }

   fprintf(stderr,"DEBUG:  allocating space for counts\n");
   int *As=calloc(sizeof(int),slen);
   int *Gs=calloc(sizeof(int),slen);
   int *Cs=calloc(sizeof(int),slen);
   int *Ts=calloc(sizeof(int),slen);
   int *Is=calloc(sizeof(int),slen);
   if(!As || !Gs || !Cs || !Ts || !Is)boom(" Could not allocate memory for counts");
   fprintf(stderr,"DEBUG:  counting\n");
   for(i=0;i<records;i++){
      for(j=0; j <slen; j++){
         int base=toupper(aligned[i][j]);
         if(     base == 'A'){ As[j]++; }
         else if(base == 'G'){ Gs[j]++; }
         else if(base == 'C'){ Cs[j]++; }
         else if(base == 'T'){ Ts[j]++; }
         else{                 Is[j]++; }
      }
   }
   fprintf(stderr,"DEBUG:  emitting\n");
   for(j=0;j<slen;j++){
       fprintf(stdout,"%5d %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d\n",j,As[j],Gs[j],Cs[j],Ts[j],Is[j]);
   }

}

void boom(char *string){
   printf("Fatal error: %s\n",string);
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: Without looking at your code: this type of question comes up occasionally, and the answer is usually either, "Because Perl isn't C" or "Your Perl code and C code are not equivalent." Example: [Why does this perl script run way slower than it's c counterpart?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19234356/176646)

Comment: You are operating on strings as if they were C strings, where you have to deal with individual characters and extract and index them.  This is not the Perlish way of dealing with strings.  In Perl, all the mechanics of string handling are hidden behind the scenes for you.

Answer (score 2):

I misunderstood your question. Here is another attempt to solve it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;
use Time::HiRes qw{ time };

my $insertPoint = 100000;
my @alignedSeqs;
push @alignedSeqs, join '', map qw(A C G T X)[rand 5], 1 .. $insertPoint for 1 .. 3000;

my $start = time();

my %count;
for my $i (0 .. $#alignedSeqs) {
    my $j = 0;
    for my $ch (split //, $alignedSeqs[$i]) {
        ++$count{$ch}[$j++]
    }
}
for my $ch (keys %count) {
    next if $ch =~ /[ACTGI]/;
    $count{I}[$_] += $count{$ch}[$_] for 0 .. $insertPoint;
    delete $count{$ch};
}


my $end = time();

print Dumper \%count;
print $count{A}[0] + $count{C}[0] + $count{G}[0] + $count{T}[0] + $count{I}[0], "\n";
print $end - $start, " seconds\n";
```

Or, slightly faster (90 versus 60 seconds), using substr references:

```
my $s = $alignedSeqs[0];
my @p = map \ substr($s, $_, 1), 0 .. $insertPoint - 1;


for my $i (0 .. $#alignedSeqs) {
    $s = $alignedSeqs[$i];
    my $j = 0;
    for my $ch (@p) {
        ++$count{$$ch}[$j++]
    }
}
for my $ch (keys %count) {
    next if $ch =~ /[ACTGI]/;
    $count{I}[$_] += $count{$ch}[$_] for 0 .. $insertPoint - 1;
    delete $count{$ch};
}
```

Comment: Isn't that counting the number of each letter (C, for instance) in each of the $alignedSeqs?  That isn't the right calculation.  Think of the $alignedSeqs as a two dimensional array of characters and each $alignedSeq[$i] is a row of that array.  It needs to calculate the number of characters down the columns, not across the rows.

Comment: Using `tr` is clever, and probably faster than calling substr multiple times on the principle of "do as much work as possible inside Perl".  However, calling that dispatch routine inside the inner loop will be extraordinarily slow.  Anything gained by hard coding `$char` in the `tr` will be killed by subroutine call overhead and it makes the code more complicated to understand.  You're far better off just calling `tr/$char//` inline.

Comment: Tempted to benchmark `eval "tr/$char//"` vs. `/$char/g`

Comment: @Schwern: tr/// doesn't interpolate.

Comment: @choroba I think he meant to use `eval` every time instead of calling prepared function.

Comment: @mpapec [Why fight temptation](https://gist.github.com/schwern/90caaccb4127cb8a98f3)?  (spoiler: tr is significantly faster, even with the eval)  And yes, I'd forgotten that tr doesn't interpolate.  Still better to do the eval inline.

Comment: @Schwern: I forked your gist and added the eval_sub. It doesn't perform badly, it's comparable to unrolled tr.

Comment: @Schwern tnx, the difference is more than obvious. Btw, I've added `eval_sub` to your benchmark and it seems that calling a function is not such big overhead? https://gist.github.com/mpapec/29ec920803da760a1bd8

Answer (score 1):

This `my @As=(0) x $insertPoint;` is probably a waste of time and memory.  Preloading an array with a bunch of scalars (each of which is allocated memory) is not efficient.  What you might be looking for is `my @As; $#As = $insertPoint + 1` which will grow just the array without populating it.  But Perl is efficient about growing arrays.  This step is unnecessary and will cause problems down the road as the array won't return its true length.

As for the loop, I would try using a hash of arrays to eliminate the if/else chain.  And to use for loop iterators instead of manual for loops, Perl can optimize them better.

```
for my $i (0..$records-1) {
   for my $j (0..$insertPoint-1) {
      my $base = uc(substr($alignedSeqs[$i],$j,1));
      $Bases{$base}[$j]++;
   }
}
```

You may wish to post your original data problem as another question and get some fresh approaches.

In the end, the only way you're going to find out where your code is spending its time is to use a profiler like [Devel::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf).  Also, in the end, processing integers and character-by-character is something C is really fast at and it's going to be hard to beat.

Comment: Good suggestions.  Changing the for loops as you suggest knocked the time down from 210s to 169s.   Then using the $Bases hash/index dropped it further to 100s.  So now its only 100x slower than C :-).

Comment: Minor quibble - it is $records-1 and $insertPoint-1.

Comment: @mathog choroba's solution using tr eliminates the need for the inner loop (or shoves it inside Perl where it is done in C) and is likely to be much faster.  Without seeing your code and data to reproduce the whole runtime, I can't do more.